# render methods display text of full ActiveRecord relation object Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model that have relations many to many with 3 other models

### Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # == Relationships ==============================================================================

  has_and_belongs_to_many :hobbies, join_table: 'hobbies_users'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs, join_table: 'jobs_users'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :degrees, join_table: 'degrees_users'


end
```

```
class Degree < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: 'degrees_users'

end
```

the other models looks the same.

I also have a controller for the user with his index method

### Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

### View

In the view I want to render every User within a Card "Shared" layout.

```
<h1>Usuarios</h1>

<div class="container">
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render "card", user: user %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

#### Shared card

it's a card from a template.

```
<div class="frontside">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <p><%= image_tag "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10474224/pexels-photo-10474224.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-rodnae-productions-10474224.jpg&fm=jpg", class: "img-fluid" %></p>
            <h4 class="card-title"> <%= user.name %></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><%= user.description %></p>
            <a href="https://www.fiverr.com/share/qb8D02" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## On localhost browser

when I look the index of user in local host, it renders de cards for every user, but at the end it **renders the ActiveRecord array at the bottom as plain text**.

I don't understand why.

Here's a screen shoot of what I'm saying. I don't know how to get rid of it

[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kQSU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `=` from the line in which you iterate all users and change it to this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render "card", user: user %>
<% end %>
```

A `<%=` in ERB indicates that your want to output the result of the following statement. This is what you want with each `<%= render "card", user: user %>` because those lines return rendered HTML.

But `<% @users.each do |user| %>` is only used to iterate all users, you do not want to output the response of the `@users.each` call which is only a string representation of an `Enumerator`